# How to save multiple records in the saveRecord function through nlapi methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, netsuite

I have customized the default promotion form in which if a user clicks on a particular promotion the form will show dynamic elements using jquery ( as we have not created the fields or lists/records for this requirement).

so based on the data we may need to create multiple records while submitting the form. I have created the saveRecord() function in js file which is already mapped with the form. In that am trying to create promotionRecord dynamically. But cant save the record I am getting "the items you requested in the record have been deleted since you retrieved the form" error. What could be the problem and is it possible to save multiple record in single form submit?

```
departments = Object.keys(samplePromotions);
  $.each(departments, function(key,value){
    console.log(samplePromotions[value]);
    promotion = nlapiCreateRecord('customrecord_promotion');
    console.log(promotion);
    //required
    promotion.setFieldValue('name','jAVASCRIPT pROMOTION cREATION_'+value);
    promotion.setFieldValue('custrecord_px_promotion_id','js_prom_creation_'+value);
    id = (Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000));
    console.log(id);
    promotion.setFieldValue('id',id);

    var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(promotion);
```

Comment: maybe because there is no code to compile? post code!

Comment: @morels what do you mean by that? I am getting the console log of the object created and assinged values also. but while saving i am getting the error. I have udpated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem in your code, but to answer your question you can only submit one record with the API.

I would just create an array and loop through the length of it and call `nlapiCreateRecord` and the `nlapiSubmitRecord` for each one.

-- Edit
Not sure about this, but this looks weird to me to.  You are setting the `id` using `setFieldValue` method, which I believe is the external Id.  Then you are setting setting `id` again with the `nlapiSubmitRecord` call.  This returns the internal Id.  Maybe that is causing issues as well?

Comment: yes, I expect this answer, submit one record with the API. So one submit for one record in script..

Answer (score 1):

Must be this line

```
promotion.setFieldValue('id',id);
```

The id field on the record object contains the internal id of the record.  This is generated by NetSuite when you create a record.